# Classes de validação Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia!!

Uso a bastante tempo algumas classes de validação (CPF, e-mail, CNPJ) no momento estou começando a migrar para laravel ai surgiu a duvida. Onde eu coloco estas classes de validação?

O que as boas praticas do laravel recomendam? 
Coloco as classes em um determinado diretório e chamo de la? (se sim qual diretório) 
Ou devo colocar estes métodos em um controller ou em um middleware?

O que as boas praticas do laravel recomendam?

Muito obrigado

Comment: Tudo que estiver dentro da pasta `\app` é carrgado pelo autoload, caso você queira importar basta criar uma pasta, jogar la e depois importar onde precisar ... Mas você pode criar um validator customizado e utilizar a lógica das suas classes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe request que será responsável por isso, como?
Segue o link da documentação do Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

Exemplo:

No seu controller vai ter um método de criar um novo usuário.

```
public function createUser(UserRequest $request){
      // logica para criar o usuário
}
```

*Obsevação, em vez de usar o `Request $request` padrão, você cria uma classe, que você modificar como bem quiser, nela você passa as mensagens de erro e campos requeridos.

Como criar uma classe `Request`? 
use o comando do artisan: `php artisan make:request NomeDaRequest`, por padrão ela vai ser criada na pasta `request/` basta procurar na sua IDE que você vai encontrar.

Dentro dessa nova classe Request, você tem 2 métodos que vai usar para enviar mensagens de erros dos campos e os campos chamados obrigatórios, são eles o `rules()` e o `messages()`. O `rules()` ele verifica os campos obrigatórios e `messages()` exibe as mensagens de erros.

```
public function messages(){
    return [
          'title.required' => 'A title is required',
          'body.required'  => 'A message is required',
    ];
}

public function rules(){
       return [
              'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
              'body' => 'required',
       ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo... tem que criar uma custom validation.

Da uma olhada aqui:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules

É fácil e fica organizado... Costumo colocar uma pasta em App\Validations  e crio uma classe AppValidator... dentro dessa classe coloca minhas validações customizadas...

Qualquer dúvida...

Comment: Esse eu não sabia, mas prefiro criar uma classe. Me atente muito bem, ate quando eu uso regex

Comment: @RomuloSousa, Isso que postei é uma REGRA customizada... Eu também crio classes para validação... 

O que eu postei acima é pra tu poderes fazer isso na request:

$rule = ['cpf' => 'required|cpf'];

Tu cria a regra da validação.